# How to connect my docker with SSL in local network (without domain)?

Tags: docker, nginx, raspberry-pi, lets-encrypt

I wanted to know if there was a way to secure the traffic between my Rapsberry Pi, which runs Docker, and my computer on the same local network with SSL protocol. I just want to be able to connect HTTPS to my containers, just in local with let's encrypt (I use raspberrypi.local domain).

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SSL to connect to a local (not registered) domain, but not using letsencrypt.

Letsencrypt (and any other service that provides certificates) needs to verify the ownership of the domain in order to deploy a certificate.
This is done in various ways (out of the scope of this question) but in any case, an existing domain name, publicly resolvable, must exist.
This is not your case obviously.

What you can do, is generate a self-signed certificate and use that to connect through SSL.

This is a tutorial for generating an SSL certificate using docker only: https://codefresh.io/blog/using-docker-generate-ssl-certificates/

Once you have a certificate, you have to deploy it in your docker app stack, but I guess this is off-topic for your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,
So if I understand correctly, I can secure my connection with SSL but it must be on the side of the application?

Comment: Nope. It's a standard SSL connection. The only difference is that you don't have a third party (such as letsencrypt, godaddy, rapidssl, ...) That gives you a certificate, but you build a certificate yourself.

Comment: To clarify, letsencrypt or any public CA must verify you 'own' the domain-name(s) -- or really just _control_ it(them); legal title of a domain-name is at best complicated. FYI 'property' is used in English for things someone or something owns or possesses -- "this car is my property and has the color green" -- and not the reverse -- "the color property of this car is green" but only quite rare "the _proprietor_ (owner) of this car is me".

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Comment: "What you can do, is generate a self-signed certificate and use that to connect through SSL." Better yet, create a CA Authority and add the CA's Root Certifiacte to each container's trust store.  Then you can sign each container's certificate with the CA key and certificate validation will work perfectly.